# .click stops working after using replaceWith

Tags: jquery, html, replacewith

Okay, I have been stuck on this for a little while now...

Basically I have two way I want a certain div to be displayed.  I was planning on creating a function with a replaceWith() replacing #mainDiv with another version of #mainDiv.

Here is the function:

```
function switchToChoice(){
            $('#myCanvas2').replaceWith('<div id="yesBox" width="150" height="90"><img id="yes" src="Yes-Button.png" width="110" height="55"></div><div id="noBox" width="150" height="90"><img id="no" class src="No-Button.png" width="110" height="55"></div>');

        }
```

This works and creates the div box I want when it is called.  The div box has two images in it, which are clickable, but the click actions are not performed.

This is the piece of code that is not working after the replaceWith:

```
//If the user presses the Next button on the comment pages.
        $('#next').click(function() {
            $('#next').fadeTo(100, 0.25, function(){
                clearCanvas(ctx, c);
                wrapText(ctx, questionList[textPos], x, y-20, 275, 15);
                textPos++;
            });
            switchToChoice();
            $('#next').fadeTo(100, 1);
        });

        //If the user presses the Yes button on the question pages.
        $('#yes').click(function() {
            alert("boobs");
            $('#yes').fadeTo(100, 0.25, function(){
                clearCanvas(ctx, c);
                wrapText(ctx, questionList[textPos], x, y-20, 275, 15);
                textPos++;
            });
            $('#yes').fadeTo(100, 1);
        });

        //If the user presses the No button on the question pages.
        $('#no').click(function() {
            $('#no').fadeTo(100, 0.25, function(){
                clearCanvas(ctx, c);
                wrapText(ctx, questionList[textPos], x, y-20, 275, 15);
                textPos++;
            });
            $('#no').fadeTo(100, 1);
        });
```

My guess is that something is lost when the HTML is replaced, but I really don't know what.  I am fairly new to JQuery and have done as much research as possible, but it seems like I am just going in circles.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

You are creating elements dynamically, you need to use Event delegation using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Your events will be attached only to the elements existing in DOM at that time. So you need to use Delegated event by attaching the event to the document or to the parent element that exists at any point in time. You can do that by using `on()`

```
     $(document).on('click', '#next', function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.25, function(){
            clearCanvas(ctx, c);
            wrapText(ctx, questionList[textPos], x, y-20, 275, 15);
            textPos++;
        });
        switchToChoice();
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 1);
    });

    //If the user presses the Yes button on the question pages.
    $(document).on('click','#yes', function() {
        alert("boobs");
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.25, function(){
            clearCanvas(ctx, c);
            wrapText(ctx, questionList[textPos], x, y-20, 275, 15);
            textPos++;
        });
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 1);
    });

    //If the user presses the No button on the question pages.
     $(document).on('click','#no', function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.25, function(){
            clearCanvas(ctx, c);
            wrapText(ctx, questionList[textPos], x, y-20, 275, 15);
            textPos++;
        });
        $(this).fadeTo(100, 1);
    });
```

Comment: APart from that when you are inside the event you can refer to the element with $(this)

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was reading about .on, but I didn't really understand and couldn't find any examples that made sense with my code.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, when you replace the html, the event is getting broken.

As I look at what you're replacing it with, there is no element with event of #next on it. You have ids of yesBox, yes, noBox and no, but nothing with next. Which means you're not clicking on anything that meets the criteria.

**EDIT**

Since the #yes and #no boxes that you are trying to access don't exist until after you replace the HTML, the events can't be bound to them in the way you're trying.

Instead, try something like this:

```
$('#myCanvas').on('click', '#yes', function(){})
```

This actually binds the event to the `myCanvas` div, BUT will only trigger for children elements that have an id of `yes` (the second parameter of the on function.)

This way the event is bound to the div, which stays even after you replace the HTML.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't include them.  There are two more .click() calls for the #yes and #no div boxes.  They are basically identical to the one I posted for #next.  I updated the question.

Comment: And the .click for #no and #yes are the ones that are not working.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was reading about .on, but I didn't really understand and couldn't find any examples that made sense with my code.